# Как отследить транзакцию по любому адресу в bitcoin без использования обозревателей и без развертывания собственной полной ноды?

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain

Мне необходимо в реальном (или близком к реальному) времени отслеживать появление транзакции по любому, нужному мне адресу в блокчейне bitcoin без использования обозревателей (ограничения и лимиты по использованию API могут сильно мешать) и без подъема собственной полной ноды. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите, код биткоин, благо он полностью открыт, в теории Вы можете получать блоки, которые нужно смайнить или уже смайнены. Но всё равно Вам придется их проверить на наличие нужного Вам адреса, зато Вы не будете смотреть всю ноду. По-другому это сделать нельзя